# Warning when creating shape in xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to define a shape in an XML doc as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#00FF00"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

However, I get the following warnings and errors:

1. Layout width and height to be defined (no example shows these as
   being defined)
2. Element corners not allowed here
3. element stroke not allowed here

How can I clear these errors?

Comment: I implement your code. it is not giving me any type of error or warning. It works for me. I implemented in eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That XML file should be located in `res/drawable`. Given the errors you just mentioned I assume it is located in `res/layout`, which is an incorrect location.

Comment: thanks. Can I put it in any of the drawable folders, or does it make a difference in which folder e.g. drawable-mdpi I put it?

Comment: In general no, unless you want to provide specific drawables for different screen resolutions. But if you want it to be available for all screen resolutions, then you could create a new folder called `drawable` (res/drawable) and put the resources there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem due to the fact that i surrounded the same code with tag "selector", it was put automatically from android studio. "selector" must be changed with "shape" for have border and avoid warning